# RSS for Google Finance news

Tags: android, rss, google-finance-api

I am making a Google Finance application and searching for the APIs.

I have found the API on Google Finance site but there news also coming.

I have tried to search but could not get the API for the news.

Can you please guide me in this regard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did u check this http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/ It has all search API's that you may need. If need updates from Google News, you can use RSS feeds as well

Comment: but this is java script. i dnt wan use java script .
i am trying to find the rss reader .
hopefully some things work .

Comment: there are ways to get it done, without using javascript, read the documentation carefully. And pls mark the answer if it answers ur query

Comment: hi, i have studied the documentation but didn't find anything useful.
ultimately i need to parse html page for getg streaming news on google finance page .
can u suggest me gud parser for it ? thanks .